# Search as enter text in entry of Xamarin Forms

Tags: search, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Studio on Mac machine and working on Xamarin Forms project. My requirement is - I have Entry field, OnTextChanged event of entry field I want to display only those item in ListView which are starting with entered text. For this moment, I am using below code to implement it-

```
entry_excludeIngredients.TextChanged += (s, e) => {

                listof_excludeIngredients.ItemsSource = container;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry_excludeIngredients.Text))
                {
                    listof_excludeIngredients.ItemsSource = null;
                    listof_excludeIngredients.IsVisible=false;
                } 
                else
                {
                    listof_excludeIngredients.ItemsSource = container.Where(x => x.StartsWith(entry_excludeIngredients.Text));
                    if(listof_excludeIngredients.ItemsSource==null)
                        listof_excludeIngredients.IsVisible=false;
                    else
                        listof_excludeIngredients.IsVisible=true;
                }

            };
```

But I am facing one issue that is above code is case-sensitive. If you enter "r" ListView is showing only results starts with "r" but not with "R".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
listof_excludeIngredients.ItemsSource = container.Where(x => x.StartsWith(entry_excludeIngredients.Text));
```

to

```
listof_excludeIngredients.ItemsSource = container.Where(x => x.StartsWith(entry_excludeIngredients.Text,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Glad it helped :).@DipakAkhade